# Can you talk on the iPhone and use Siri with Monster beats headphones?

Tags: iphone, siri, voice-dictation

I want a set of Beats by Dre headphones and have seen that they come with a control on the cord. Does this have a Mic? and can it be used with Siri in the same way the official Apple ones can?

I have looked at online reviews etc, but little is mentioned with iPhone voice compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes.

The Monster Beats cables are fully compatible with Apple hardware. They have a mic to support voice actions and Siri. They also have all the hardware buttons for playing music and making phone calls.

I happen to own the Beats Solo headphones.  This is what the **packaging** says:

> "Made for iPod", "Made for iPhone" and "Made for iPad" mean that an
> electronic accessory has been **designed to connect specifically** to
> iPod, iPhone or iPad, respectively, and has been **certified by the
> developer to meet Apple performance standards**.
>
> (also see [MiF logo](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) on Apple's website)

These minimum standards would include voice and button actions using the headset.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

You should be okay. The beats headphones mic is simply an extension of the built-in mic. Additionally, the hardware to filter out background noise is inside of your iPhone and so the mic won't make much of a difference. Can you do same thing with your standard Apple headphones, right? It's the same thing.

I personally use Klipsch ONE headphones with my iPhone 4. It works well with voice commands. I used my Apple earbuds with the new iPad before. Dictation works like a charm. So, yes, you can.